# How to create NAMED-PIPE in .NET-4?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

How to create NAMED-PIPE in .NET-4 in your C# application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a piece of code to create a Named Pipe client, it is lifted from an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697820/how-to-send-messages-between-c-dll-and-c-app-using-named-pipe/2703831#2703831) I answered on communicating between C++ and C# using Named Pipes

```
using System; 
using System.Text; 
using System.IO; 
using System.IO.Pipes; 

namespace CSPipe 
{ 
  class Program 
  { 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "HyperPipe", PipeDirection.InOut); 
      pipe.Connect(); 
      using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(pipe, Encoding.Unicode)) 
      { 
        System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadToEnd()); 
      } 

      Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using WCF:

> var binding = new System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding(System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)

Comment: Will a WCF service using a named pipe binding work with ANY app that uses named pipes? What if I have a legacy application that is using them? I'm trying to figure out if it's only WCF-WCF that's possible in this scenario.

Comment: It depends! The current implementation of named pipes does not allow them to be used across the network. Also, if you want to use them to communicate with a legacy app you'll probably need to implement the protocol that's sitting on top yourself, WCF won't know about that.  In which case it would be easier to use some of the lower-level methods, e.g. win32 (see http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244367/c-3-5-connecting-named-pipe-across-network.