# How to launch Excel with an XLSX stream

Tags: excel, openxml, excel-2010

i've constructed an XLSX document in memory.

i want to display the document to the user *without having to save a temporary file*.

In the olden days i would simply automate Excel, and make

```
xl.Visible = true;
```

and the user would see it - no temporary files littering their computer.

But i'm hoping to standardize on one code-base for [server-side creation of Excel documents, and interactive creation of Excel documents](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). On the server i would send the Stream down the `HttpResponse`, or as an SMTP attachment, and be done with it.

Now i need a way to *stream* content into client-side Excel.

Comment: If your server is pushing out a stream and you're using some type of HTTP server, you can always specify the MIME type as application/vnd.ms-excel and you're done (with your browser taking care of the temp file automatically).  If this is a local client that needs to grab data from a web service, then I'd suggest creating a named pipe and feeding your Excel document stream that way.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045304/how-to-create-named-pipe-in-net-4

Comment: That's fine when the XLSX spreadsheet is being built in a web-server. But i when it's being build by a local Win32 applications: there is no web-server; it's a local Win32 application.

Comment: Sounds like the NamedPipe is your easiest solution.  Just create the XLSX stream, feed it to the pipe, and have your automation open Excel with that as the input file argument.